# Nutch querying on the fly

Tags: solr, nutch

I am a newbie to nutch and solr. Well relatively much newer to Solr than Nutch :)

I have been using nutch for past two weeks, and I wanted to know if I can query or search on my nutch crawls on the fly(before it completes). I am asking this because the websites I am crawling are really huge and it takes around 3-4 days for a crawl to complete. I want to analyze some quick results while the nutch crawler is still crawling the URLs. Some one suggested me that Solr would make it possible.

I followed the steps in http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/03/09/nutch-solr/ for this. I see only the injected URLs are shown in the Solr search. I know I did something really foolish and the crawl never happened, I feel I am missing some information here. But I did all the steps mentioned in the link. I think somewhere in the process there should be a crawling happening and which is missed.

Just wanted to see if some one could help me pointing this out and where I went wrong in the process. Forgive my foolishness and thanks for your patience.

Cheers,
Abi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.
What you could do though is chunk the crawl cycle in a smaller number of URL's such that it will publish result more often whith this command
`nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments -topN  <the limit>`
If you are using the onestop command `craw`l it should be the same.

I typically have a 24hours chunking scheme.